# Creating a Couchbase bucket with Scala?

Tags: scala, couchbase

I'm trying to create a couchbase bucket using scala.  I have the following setup:

```
val cluster: Cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("127.0.0.1")

val bucketSettings: BucketSettings = new DefaultBucketSettings.Builder().`type`(BucketType.COUCHBASE).name("test").quota(100)

cluster.clusterManager("Administrator","password").insertBucket(bucketSettings)
```

However when I run this I get the following error:

```
com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseException: Could not insert bucket: {"errors":{"ramQuotaMB":"RAM quota specified is too large to be provisioned into this cluster."},"summaries":{"ramSummary":{"total":8892973056,"otherBuckets":8892973056,"nodesCount":1,"perNodeMegs":100,"thisAlloc":104857600,"thisUsed":0,"free":-104857600},"hddSummary":{"total":249678528512,"otherData":162290338027,"otherBuckets":705505,"thisUsed":0,"free":87387484980}}}
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this?  I don't have any other buckets.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have 8GB of RAM?

Comment: On my couchbase account?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is sort of in the reply.  You've already allocated all of your memory so you can't create more buckets:
`"total":8892973056,"otherBuckets":8892973056`